# Is there a way to add retina images on openlayers 3 map

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a retina image of 500x500 pixels but it has to be displayed as 250x250 on map.

If i scale the image the quality is reduced.

Is there a way we can display retina images on the openlayers 3 map.

I use this style to display images

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        src: imagesource,
    })),
});
```